# JQuery apply css to a class only on homepage

Tags: jquery, css

So right now I have a ul set to visibile:hidden, but I only want it to be visible at all times when the user is on the homepage.

I have something like this:

```
if ((window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/") != (window.location.href)) {
        $('ul.top-nav .nav .nested-menu-mobile').css("visibility","visible","important");
 }
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: why don't you embed it in the homepage file only

Comment: I should clarify. It's on a template where I can't do that. It is in every page no matter what and the thing it I only want it on the homepage. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/JMeN7/

Comment: you check in the source file of the homepage and check for an id or class that appears only in the hompage like a slider. Then you can create a condition if this id or class exist, execute the code

Comment: @Amir That sounds like a good idea. Excuse my noobishness, but how would I create a condition like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the source file of the homepage and check for an id or class that appears only in the homepage like a slider. Then you can create a condition if this id or class exist, execute the code

Here's an example:

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/94Yca/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
```

**JS**

```
if(document.getElementById('slider')){
    alert("Id slider exist");
}

if(document.getElementsByClassName("someClass")[0]){
    alert("Class exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.URL === 'your_URL'){
   $('ul.top-nav .nav .nested-menu-mobile').css("visibility","visible","important");
}
```

check the current url and apply the class accordingly if it matches homepage.